# How can I use React with Material UI to put grid items vertically close to each other?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, css-grid

I am new to react and Material UI but I've followed some tutorials to try to figure out how to create a chat application. I've been stuck on this bug for 2.5 hours and similar stack overflow posts haven't helped.

I am working on a chat application and I want the messages to be close to each other like this but not with all that whitespace to the right of the message:

[image]

The code that generates the above image is:

```
<Grid container spacing={2} direction="column">
  <Grid item xs={12} container sx={{backgroundColor: "#1B9CB3"}}>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <Typography variant="h5" component="div" sx={{margin: 1.5, fontFamily: 'Dongle', lineHeight: .8}}>
        Lorem
      </Typography>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={8}>
      <Typography variant="h5" component="div" sx={{margin: 1.5, color: "white", fontFamily: 'Dongle', lineHeight: .8}}>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </Typography>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} container sx={{alignItems: "center", background: "linear-gradient(0deg, #FFB27375, #FFA359);"}}>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{margin: 3, fontFamily: 'Dongle', color: "white", lineHeight: .8}}>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
      </Typography>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item container sx={{margin: 3, backgroundColor: "white", minHeight: 400, maxHeight: 400, overflow: 'auto', padding: 1.5, display: 'table'}} xs={12}>
      {listMessages(this.state.messages)}
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={8}>
      <TextField inputProps={{ maxLength: 256 }} value={this.state.message_content} onChange={this.handleTextChange} sx={{margin: 3, fontFamily: "Dongle", width: "auto"}} id="outlined-basic" label="Your message" variant="outlined" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit} sx={{margin: 3}} variant="contained">Send</Button>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>

function listMessages(messages) {
  return messages.map((message) => {
    if (message.sent) {
      return [
        <Grid item xs={3}>
        </Grid>,
        <Grid sx={{justifyContent: 'right', flexWrap: 'wrap', display: 'flex'}} item xs={9}>
          <Typography sx={{margin: 1, wordBreak: "break-word", lineHeight: .8, color: "white"}} inline variant="caption">
            <Container align="left" sx={{padding: 1, backgroundColor: "#1a9bb2", borderRadius: 1}}>
              {message.message_content}
            </Container> 
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
      ]
      
    } else {
      return [
        <Grid sx={{justifyContent: 'left', flexWrap: 'wrap', display: 'flex'}} item xs={9}>
          <Typography inline sx={{wordBreak: "break-word", margin: 1, lineHeight: .8, color: "white"}} align="left" variant="caption">
            <Container align="left" sx={{padding: 1, backgroundColor: "#ffa359", borderRadius: 1}}>
              {message.message_content}
            </Container>
          </Typography>
        </Grid>,
        <Grid item xs={3}>
        </Grid>
      ]
    }
  });
}
```

To fix this, I've gotten rid of `display: 'table'`. This gets rid of all the whitespace to the right but now there's too much whitespace in between the messages. This happens because the minWidth of the grid is set to 400 (I want the minWidth of the grid to be 400 so the chatbox isn't non-existent when there are no messages).

[image: Misaligned messages]

Eventually when there are a bunch of messages, the messages are close together like I want them:

[image: messages close together]

This modification to the code generates the above two images (Removing display: 'table'):

```
<Grid item container sx={{margin: 3, backgroundColor: "white", minHeight: 400, maxHeight: 400, overflow: 'auto', padding: 1.5}} xs={12}>
  {listMessages(this.state.messages)}
</Grid>
```

What can I do to get the messages close together no matter how many messages there are? Other comments on whether I'm using material ui's grid correctly or not are welcome too.

Comment: I dont think Grid is the best component to use in this situation. Why not just use a List?

Comment: I am using the Grid component so that when the other person responds I can align the other person's messages on the left side of the box and my messages on the right side of the box. Is there a way to do this with a List?

Comment: All that is is changing flex properties so it can be done with nearly anything

Comment: Ok I will look into the list component then :) can you tell me why it would be better to use the list component in this situation?